# Extracting data stored tables in .docx file with C#

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, .doc

When I run the following code on a .docx file the child2.innerText will print out the information I am after (although without seperating text from the seperate columns of the table). 

 My problem is that the associated innerXml is completely incomprehensible for me. I thought that there would be an 'get cell from table' method or such. I have literally no idea how to extract columns/rows from the xml I've been given though.

I'm completely new to C#, so I might be missing something obvious.

 I am using the openxml and the file is .docx.

```
        using (WordprocessingDocument wdoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pathToMiniToktrapport, false))
        {

            var table = wdoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Table>();
            foreach (var child in table)
            {
                foreach (var child2 in child) {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(child2.InnerXml);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(child2.InnerText);
                    System.Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
         }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go through the link in MSDN which shows the typical structure and sample code

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850835.aspx

Comment: I'm not going to excuse myself, but I am. I did check that out but I was looking for a .getCellMethod() and didn't understand that I was looking for .getElements<> methods.